# How do I access an object value in a map fetched and extracted from firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner self-learner in dart so forgive me a trivial question for most pros (that's my first one ever though).
So here it goes:

I am fetching data from Firebase with this code:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetData() async {
    final url =
        'my end point URL';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (extractedData == null) {
      return;
    }
final List<CarData> loadedCars = [];
extractedData.forEach((carId, carDetails) {
  loadedCars.add(
      CarData(
    id: carDetails['id'],
    title: carDetails['year'],
    emotion: carDetails['brand'],
    timeStamp: carDetails['timeStamp'],
  ));
```

Now, I get an example map  (just one entry in Firebase for now):

```
print(extractedData);
```

result:

```
{-MTGYiJ-P8fN0qhQ3_zC: {brand: Ferrari, id: -MS8qMI3FtVxMBg3P9hm, timeStamp: 2021-02-11T15:46:38.550621, year: 2019}}
```

CartData values are stored properly and I managed to display them in a GridView. Although, I need to count all Ferraris in the database but I cannot access the object values inside the map.

when I:

```
 print(extractedData.keys);
 print(extractedData.values);
```

I get proper response (I guess):

```
I/flutter (18184): (-MTGYiJ-P8fN0qhQ3_zC)
I/flutter (18184): ({brand: Ferrari, id: -MS8qMI3FtVxMBg3P9hm, timeStamp: 2021-02-11T15:46:38.550621, year: 2019})
```

But when I:

```
print(extractedData.containsValue('Ferrari'));
```

I get response: 'false' and without this I cannot do anything with further counting logic.

Could someone please enlight me what am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :
print(extractedData.values.toString().contains('Ferrari'));

Comment: many thanks! it works :) do you know why this problem appeared? both extraxtedData and extractedData.toString() look the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `jsonDecode` your JSON String:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final jsonStr = '{"-MTGYiJ-P8fN0qhQ3_zC": {"brand": "Ferrari", "id": "-MS8qMI3FtVxMBg3P9hm", "timeStamp": "2021-02-11T15:46:38.550621", "year": "2019"}}';
  final data = jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  print(data.values.first['brand']);
}
```

---

You could also go one step further by defining a Domain Model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part '66165017.json.freezed.dart';
part '66165017.json.g.dart';

void main() {
  final jsonStr =
      '{"-MTGYiJ-P8fN0qhQ3_zC": {"brand": "Ferrari", "id": "-MS8qMI3FtVxMBg3P9hm", "timeStamp": "2021-02-11T15:46:38.550621", "year": 2019}}';
  final Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  final List<MyModel> list =
      json.values.map((entry) => MyModel.fromJson(entry)).toList();
  print(list.firstWhere((entry) => entry.brand == 'Ferrari'));
  // MyModel(brand: Ferrari, id: -MS8qMI3FtVxMBg3P9hm, date: null, year: 2019)
}

@freezed
abstract class MyModel with _$MyModel {
  factory MyModel([String brand, String id, DateTime date, int year]) =
      _MyModel;

  factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MyModelFromJson(json);
}
```

I used the following packages:

- [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for the my immutable Model
- [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) for the JSON encode/decode

These two packages are generating extra code in `66165017.json.freezed.dart` for `freezed` and `66165017.json.g.dart` for `json_serializable`.

Comment: many thanks! just two questions, the string I have is already result of json.decode()  (of firebase response.  So you have not meant decoding again have you? I will have to work this idea further. What are the files part '66165017.json.freezed.dart'; part '66165017.json.g.dart'; ? When I add them dart returns an error even though I installed freezed annotation and freezed.

Comment: My main dart file is `66165017.json.dart` and the convention used by `freezed` is to add `.freezed` and `.g` for the generated files.

Comment: `extractedData` is a `Map<String, dynamic> containing `{'-MTGYiJ-P8fN0qhQ3_zC': {'brand': 'Ferrari'}}`. This is why your search should target the brand and not the whole map.

Comment: I also updated my solution to show you how you would use it with a list of cars.